# Bug collision probability problem

Tags: probability

There is one bug per $V_k$ $(k=\overline{1,n})$ vertex and the $C$ centre of the regular n-gon. The bugs begin to move along the sides of the n-gon and the line through $V_kC$. What is the probability that bugs will not meet?

I was trying to use a similar logic with http://puzzles.nigelcoldwell.co.uk/fortysix.htm. But it seems this problem needs a different approach.

Comment: So each bug initially has three options? Do they choose one of these three uniformly independently at random? What happens when they've reached their destination, is that it or do they choose again? Is the polygon regular? (That may not matter depending on the answers to the other questions.)

Comment: @joriki Yeah, sorry. The polygon is regular. The original question states "bugs begin to move". So what can one conclude?

Comment: @joriki bugs on the vertex have 3 options, and the bug on the center has $n$

Comment: I gather from your response that there's an original question that you paraphrased. That's usually a bad idea and often results in errors of transmission. Please quote the entire original question verbatim and provide its source.

Comment: @joriki edited accordingly. Now it's same as the original)

Comment: Either you've made errors in copying the question, or it contains grammatical errors ("the $C$ centre" instead of "the centre $C$", "bugs" instead of "the bugs"). As I said, please provide the source of the question. Please see [this answer on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29298) on why to provide the source.

Comment: @joriki it was a problem from my control work at school and English is not my native language nor my teacher's. So, sorry for the mistakes

Comment: OK, thanks, that helps to assess the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are not told the bugs will change their motion when they reach the destination towards which they started moving, we can only assume that they’ll either stop at the destination or keep going in a straight line (thus leaving the polygon at some point).

If so, they can meet either halfway towards their destination if they started moving along the same line, or at their destination if they chose the same destination; after that they will never meet.

If more than one vertex bug chooses the centre as their destination, they will meet there. Thus we have two cases to consider: $0$ bugs choose the centre or $1$ bug chooses the centre.

If $0$ bugs choose the centre, they must all go in the same direction (clockwise or counterclockwise), so no matter where the centre bug goes, it will meet one of them at the destination, so this case cannot occur.

That leaves only the option that $1$ bug from some vertex $v$ goes to the centre. The remaining vertex bugs still all have to go in the same direction (clockwise or counterclockwise), since otherwise either two adjacent ones will meet halfway or the two adjacent to $v$ will meet at $v$. For each direction, there’s exactly one vertex that the centre bug can go to (one of the two vertices adjacent to $v$).

So there are $2n$ ways for them not to meet, out of $3^n\cdot n$ choices, so assuming that the bugs all uniformly independently choose one of their options (the question fails to specify this), the probability for them not to meet is $2\cdot3^{-n}$.

Note that the question is equivalent to counting the [Hamiltonian cycles](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html) in the [wheel graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WheelGraph.html) $W_n$, of which there are $n$; the factor $2$ arises because the bugs can travel along the cycle in either direction.

Comment: Thank you, sir. And sorry for the defects in the question.